# Uploading Node.js app to cloudfoundry withour express error

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, vmc

Im trying to upload a node.js app into cloud foundry, im not going to use Express Framework, but when doing "vcm push" Im getting this error.

```
Uploading Application:
No such file or directory - /Users/jtomasrl/Code/node/pronto/node_modules/express
```

here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "karaoke-api",
"version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "pronto": "*",
    "pronto-mongodb": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, had you already pushed to the same application with express installed? if so, it may be worth deleting the application from CloudFoundry and pushing again. It also may be worth emptying your node_modules folder and installing them again with npm. Failing that I am also happy to take a copy of your application and try and deploy myself.

Comment: it was my first try pushing the app, i was able to make it work using this command: rm -r node_modules/.bin/

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of providing an "answer", when this situation does arise, it's worth emptying node_modules/.bin or even removing node_modules itself and re-installing modules with;

```
npm install
```